# Paint Method within an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, paint, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I am trying to use the Java paint method within an ActionListener. However, when paint is placed within the ActionListener, my compiler throws errors, and eclipse does not recognize paint as a method at all, despite importing java.awt.geom.*;

```
private class NumHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
              //Draw Ovals
              public void paint (Graphics g)
              {
                   int number;
                   int x = 10;
                   int y = 30;
                   int width = 20;
                   int height = 10;

                   number = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());

                   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                   {
                        g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);

                        x += 5;
                        y += 5;
                        width += 5;
                        height += 5;
                   }
              }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `paint` method cannot be inside your `actionPerformed` method. It needs to exist as a class member method of your component rather than `NumHandler`. You could place a single `repaint()` call in your `ActionListener` method to *request* that a repaint be carried out.

Don't place any logic that is likely to lead to an exception in your `paint` method, namely:

```
number = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
```

This is better done in the `actionPerformed` method.

Also if using Swing, `paintComponent` is preferred for optimized paint performance. Remember to call `super.paintComponent(g);` to repaint any child components.

See: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: I have done what you instructed, which explains a lot to me. However, upon the action event, nothing is drawn. Do I need a JPanel?

Comment: I would say to please put back the old code from the original question and post a new question. Otherwise this answer won't make any sense. I am happy to answer any new posts. :)

Comment: Will do. This answer did effectively address my originally stated question.